# Assigning each member of an object array with values from an xml file

Tags: c#, xml, arrays, object

I have a program where the variable week is made up of object array[7] days and days is made up of object array[9] hours. Each hours object has 3 data members. I want to assign each member of a particular day and hour a specific value from an xml file:

```
   <parent> 
        <day>wednesday
            <hour>18.00 
                <value1>5</value1>
                <value2>10</value2>
                <value3>15</value3>
            </hour>
        </day>
        <day>thursday
            <hour>18.00 
                <value1>2</value1>
                <value2>3</value2>
                <value3>9</value3>
            </hour> 
        </day>
   </parent>

        day[wedensday].hour[18.00].member1 = xml.day[wednesday].hour[18.00].value1
        day[wedensday].hour[18.00].member1 = xml.day[wednesday].hour[18.00].value2
        day[wedensday].hour[18.00].member1 = xml.day[wednesday].hour[18.00].value3
```

I am new to working with xml and have come up with the following pseudo code but am having difficultly implementing it:

```
    member[i] = value[i] where day[i].name == xml.day && day[i].hour[i] == xml.hour
```

If anyone could guide me or direct me to a resource that would help with this problem it would be much appreciated, thanks :)

Comment: I think you are missing root element and closing day tags. Also day name and hour value possibly should be an attributes. Can you change format of this xml, or you should parse it as is?

Comment: In the full code I have a root element and closing day tags. I don't think that day and name would need to be attributes as I am only concerned with the 3 values within the appropriate day and hour. I can change the format if required.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can parse your xml with Linq to xml:

```
XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Load(path_to_xml_file);
var week = new
{
    Days = xdoc.Descendants("day")
                .Select(day => new {
                    Name = ((XText)day.FirstNode).Value.Trim(),
                    Hours = day.Descendants("hour")
                                .Select(hour => new {
                                    Time = ((XText)hour.FirstNode).Value.Trim(),
                                    Values = hour.Elements()
                                                .Select(node => (int)node)
                                                .ToList()
                                }).ToList()
                }).ToList()
};
```

week will be strongly-typed anonymous object. Usage:

```
var daysCount = week.Days.Count; // 2 
var secondDayName = week.Days[1].Name; // thursday
var hoursInSecondDay = week.Days[1].Hours.Count; // 1
var timeOfFirstHour = week.Days[1].Hours[0].Time; // 18:00
var value3 = week.Days[1].Hours[0].Values[2]; // 9
```

Explanation:

`xdoc.Descendants("day")` returns all `<day>` nodes. But we don't need xml nodes, so we do a projection, by selecting anonymous object, which will represent day. This object has two properties - `Name` and `Hours`. Name we get from first node of `<day>` element, which is text node ('wednesday' for first day). Hours we get by selecting `<hour>` elements of `<day>` and also making projection to anonymous object representing hour. Etc.

---

If you will move day name and hour value to attributes like this:

```
<parent>
  <day name="wednesday">  
    <hour time="18.00">    
      <value1>5</value1>
      <value2>10</value2>
      <value3>15</value3>
    </hour>
  </day>
</parent>
```

Then parsing will look like:

```
XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Load(path_to_xml_file);
var week = new
{
    Days = xdoc.Descendants("day")
                .Select(day => new {
                    Name = (string)day.Attribute("name"),
                    Hours = day.Descendants("hour")
                                .Select(hour => new {
                                    Time = (string)hour.Attribute("time"),
                                    Values = hour.Elements()
                                                .Select(node => (int)node)
                                                .ToList()
                                }).ToList()
                }).ToList()
};
```

Comment: This has been a big help but could you explain the parsing a bit, specifically what is happening after .Select(day => new {...  thanks!

Comment: @user1804007 I've added some explanations, which will be good for you to understand whole parsing approach.